# Get first part from url(first root directory value only) in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have this url (www.site.com/folder1/sub-folder).

Now I just want to get only folder1 from this url. How can I do that?

I'm getting Last root url from below code but I want only first root url.

```
string s = Page.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
s = s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf("/")+1);
```

Please help me to get only first directory value.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.example.com/folder1/sub-folder");
var segs = uri.Segments;
var folder = segs[1];
```

Comment: This will give `"folder1/"` and not `"folder1"`. May be you can use `TrimEnd('/')`

Comment: This one is new for me. Nice answer, liked it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Split()` method twice like

```
string str = "www.site.com/folder1/sub-folder";
string folder = (str.Split('/')[1]).Split('/')[0];
```

Comment: Thanks. Your solution is perfect but if there is a space then I am getting %20 also in string. Is there any way to replace %20 in blank space?

Comment: @SUN, space means? give an example. BTW, you can use `Trim()` function to get rid of that.

Comment: If my url contains www.site.com/first folder then url will get like this www.site.com/first%20folder so in my string I am geting values like this first%20folder

Comment: @SUN, you can use `Replace()` method to replace that with blank space like `folder.Replace("%20"," ")`

Comment: Thanks for your help Rahul :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Split` like:

```
var value  = s.Split(new[]{'/'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
               .FirstOrDefault();
```